# Why `int()` can convert full-width-form number string but failed with full-width-form letter string?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, int, python-unicode

Code environment: python 3.5

Today I was study some Unicode knowledge, thus I know that the entire (ASCII) Latin alphabet is represented twice again in the 'Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms' Unicode block between U+FF00 and U+FFEF.

So I did a little experiment to try to find out the attributes of such kind of unicodes. And I found something interesting when play it with built-in `int()` function.

Here's the test code:

```
In [284]: chr(65300)
Out[284]: '４'

In [285]: int(chr(65300))
Out[285]: 4

In [286]: chr(65350)
Out[286]: 'ｆ'

In [287]: int(chr(65350),16)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-287-bc841b5c3225> in <module>()
----> 1 int(chr(65350),16)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: 'ｆ'

In [288]: int('f', 16)
Out[288]: 15
```

It seems that `int()` can correctly convert a full-width-form number string into a base-10 int, but it failed when try to convert a full-width-form letter string.

Then I read the [official documents for int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). It says:

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an integer literal in radix base.

Seems my code didn't violate its rule. The only explanation now is that `int()` treat `chr(65300)` as a valid '4', but didn't treat `chr(65350)` as a valid 'f'.

Why this happened? Is it something wrong behind the mechanism of int, or another mechanism should be blamed for this?

Answer (score 3):

`int()` allows any character in the numeric decimal category(`unicodedata.category(d) == 'Nd'`), so all of these characters work for decimal digits:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> digits = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(0x110000) if ud.category(chr(i)) == 'Nd')
>>> digits
'0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯෦෧෨෩෪෫෬෭෮෯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᪀᪁᪂᪃᪄᪅᪆᪇᪈᪉᪐᪑᪒᪓᪔᪕᪖᪗᪘᪙᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷᮸᮹᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉꧐꧑꧒꧓꧔꧕꧖꧗꧘꧙꧰꧱꧲꧳꧴꧵꧶꧷꧸꧹꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙꯰꯱꯲꯳꯴꯵꯶꯷꯸꯹０１２３４５６７８９'
```

The value of the character is `unicodedata.digit(c)`:

```
>>> ud.digit('４')
4
```

`int()` only allows the ASCII `a-zA-Z` for the non-decimal digits, supporting up to base 36.

However, if you use `unicodedata.normalize('NFKC',<string>)` alternate forms of `a-zA-Z` will be converted to a normalized compatibility format and it will work:

```
>>> import unicodedata as ud
>>> s = '４ｆ'
>>> int(ud.normalize('NFKC',s),16)
79
>>> hex(79)
'0x4f'
```